# JavaScript Object prototype not returned via Factory

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, ecmascript-5, prototypal-inheritance

I've managed to create a 'factory-like' function called "createHumanByGender", however, the returned object doesn't allow me to call its prototype method "Human.prototype.getFullName()".
Would there be any reason why this happening?

Code is below:

```
// get female instance of Jade
var jade = createHumanByGender.bind( this, 'Female', 'Jade', 'Taylor' )();
console.log( jade.getFullName() );


// ------------------------------------------------
// HUMAN
function Human ( forename, surname ) {
    this.forename = forename;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = 0;
}

Human.prototype = {
    getForename : function () {
        return this.forename;
    },
    getSurname : function () {
        return this.surname;
    },
    getFullName : function () {
        return this.forename + ' ' + this.surname;
    }
};


// MALE
function Male ( forename, surname ) {
    Human.call( this, forename, surname );
    this.gender = 'Male';
}
Male.prototype = Object.create( Human.prototype );


// FEMALE
function Female ( forename, surname ) {
    Human.call( this, forename, surname );
    this.gender = 'Female';
}
Female.prototype = Object.create( Human.prototype );


// GENDER
function createHumanByGender ( gender, forename, surname ) {
    return new this[gender]( forename, surname );
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that calls `createHumanByGender()` and then the code that tries to execute a method on the returned object.

Comment: Are you sure you invoke it right? Something like this `var h = createHumanByGender('Male', 'Thomas', 'Mann'); h.getFullName();`.

Comment: Where are you running this code? One of the problems with using `this` the way you are, is that in a sandbox your `Human/Male/Female` function definitions might exist in a non-global scope, but `this` will still be the implicit global object. Strict Mode will ruin your day as well. What error is being thrown?

Comment: Hey all, I was running this in my console (browser). As for the first two comments, the createHumanByGender() is at the bottom. Actually, when you move the first 3 lines at the top to the bottom, it actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are calling the constructor before the code runs that assigns the `prototype` so your object has not inherited methods from a prototype.  Move your call to the factory function to after the definition of the constructors.

Also, it's a generally bad practice to use `this` the way you are using it since it probably won't work in strict mode.  Either directly reference `window` is that's what you want or put your constructor functions as properties of some namespace object and look them up on that object directly.

This version of your code works (working [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/25hvtu74/)):

```
// ------------------------------------------------
// HUMAN
function Human ( forename, surname ) {
    this.forename = forename;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = 0;
}

Human.prototype = {
    getForename : function () {
        return this.forename;
    },
    getSurname : function () {
        return this.surname;
    },
    getFullName : function () {
        return this.forename + ' ' + this.surname;
    }
};


// MALE
function Male ( forename, surname ) {
    Human.call( this, forename, surname );
    this.gender = 'Male';
}
Male.prototype = Object.create( Human.prototype );


// FEMALE
function Female ( forename, surname ) {
    Human.call( this, forename, surname );
    this.gender = 'Female';
}
Female.prototype = Object.create( Human.prototype );


// GENDER
function createHumanByGender ( gender, forename, surname ) {
    var f = this[gender];
    return new f( forename, surname );
}

// get female instance of Jade
var jade = createHumanByGender.bind( this, 'Female', 'Jade', 'Taylor' )();
console.log( jade.getFullName() );
```

FYI, I'd suggest you change your factory function to this:

```
// GENDER
function createHumanByGender ( gender, forename, surname ) {
    var f = window[gender];
    return new f( forename, surname );
}
```

And, then call it like this:

```
// get female instance of Jade
var jade = createHumanByGender('Female', 'Jade', 'Taylor');
console.log( jade.getFullName() );
```

FYI, if you really want to cause a `this` value in a function you're going to immediately call, use `.call()` instead of `.bind()` anyway - but neither is needed here.

Comment: Changed my answer to include the main issue about running the constructors before you've assigned anything to the `prototype`.

Comment: `return new this[gender](forename, surname);` should work fine without extra parenthesis, or an intermediate. Property lookup has a higher precedence than both operator new and function invocation. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/krzczsL6/).

Comment: @Oka - Yeah, you're right. I removed that from the text of my answer.  Personally, I don't like something like that that relies on the reader of the code to know detailed precedence rules to understand exactly what it does or whether it is correct or not.  I'd rather write code that can be understood more easily.

Comment: Why are you binding `createHumanByGener` to `this` at all?  Agreed, there was noting wrong with the usage of `this` in `return new this[gender](forename, surname);`.  The only issue was calling the constructor before the prototypes were defined.

Comment: @arctelix - I think the whole use of `this` in this code is bad.  My answer says that.  The `.bind()` of `this` is the way the OP's code worked, not my idea.  I offered an answer that fixed the one issue that was keeping the OP's code from working and I suggested several ways they could write their code differently that does not use `this` at all in the factory function as it is not needed and wouldn't work in strict mode either.  I added a new part to the end of my answer that implements it without `.bind()` or `this`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Fair enough..  My comment should have been directed at the OP, not your answer.

Comment: @OluCarter - If this answers your question, then you can indicate that to the community by checking the green check mark to the left of the answer and this will earn you some reputation points for following the correct procedure with your question.  If this does not answer your question, then please explain what is still not answered.